# Compose Mercurial commands from TortoiseHg and send to remote Linux using ssh

Tags: ssh, mercurial, tortoise-hg

I use [TortoiseHg Workbench](https://web.archive.org/web/20161224181701/tortoisehg.bitbucket.org/manual/2.0/workbench.html) to manage repositories on my local windows machine, and I like how TortoiseHg composes the commands based on clicks I make using the GUI.

But I only know how to use TortoiseHg to manage local Windows repositories, not remote Unix Mercurial clients residing on a web server.

Is it possible to tunnel through SSH and send commands to a Unix web server?  I would like to manage a repo remotely on my web server using TortoiseHg.

Comment: The usual way of working with DVCS repositories is to `hg clone` the repo to your computer, then `hg push` new commits back to the server.

Comment: I use bitbucket to store the repos, and I want to pull the latest commits from bitbucket to the web server.  Do I need to pull using the web server's command line, or is there a way to send commands to my web server from TortoiseHg's windows client?  Filezilla sends commands to be executed on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible: the only "commands" you can send over SSH (and HTTPS) are `hg push` and `hg pull`.

They're not really sent as "commands", instead Mercurial uses it's own protocol which allows a client to query a remote server for a few things like "do you have this changeset?", "what are the branch heads?", and "please accept this bundle!".

When you use SSH, your Mercurial client will make a SSH tunnel and start `hg serve --stdio` on the remote host. That `hg serve` command is what speaks the Mercurial wire protocol I talk about above. Hosting environments such as Bitbucket are locked down so that this is the *only* command you can execute over SSH — they don't want you to execute arbitrary commands on their servers!

As for managing a remote repository on *your own* webserver: You need to login with SSH and create an empty repository on your Unix server:

```
$ hg init my-website
```

Then you can push to the server from your local machine:

```
$ hg push ssh://your-server.com/path/from/home-dir/to/my-website
```

Since you're talking about managing a website, you might want to add

```
[hooks]
changegroup = hg update
```

to the `.hg/hgrc` file in the remote repository: it will make Mercurial run `hg update` after every push into that repository. This means that the working copy will be updated with the latest files and so your webserver can serve these to the world.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Looks like I'll need to script on the command line to pull and updates to the server.  Not a huge deal to script, just wanted to make sure there was no way to use TortoiseHg.

Comment: This may be a little late, but if you can see the .hg directory and its contents from an external web browser, some one can do an `hg clone` of your site if I am not mistaken.